# Meaning of "low, cherry voices" in Stephen King's 'The Jaunt'

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english, literature

In Stephen King's *The Jaunt*, I found this sentence:

> Five Jaunt attendants circulate, speaking in low, cherry voices and offering glasses of milk.

It's either a typo (was supposed to be 'cheery') or something I don't understand. Can anyone think of an idea?

Comment: Have you checked another edition/version of the story to see if it's the same?

Comment: "Cherry" may describe their timbre, while "cheery" their tone. I would suppose that attendants are supposed to be unobstrusive, not mood makers.

Comment: Cherry/virginal/young/sweet?

Comment: Yes, most likely a typo.

Comment: @Lambie [Think so?](https://gist.github.com/Schemetrical/6184daf83843bcab9402?permalink_comment_id=3651690) Sure looks to me like it [always been this way.](https://ia601904.us.archive.org/35/items/the-jaunt-stephen-king/The%20Jaunt%20-%20Stephen%20King.pdf)

Comment: @tchrist Five Jaunt attendants circulated, speaking in low, cheery voices and offering glasses of milk. From the short story collection in which The Jaunt appears: chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/http://www.brunswick.k12.me.us/bhslibrary/files/2020/05/Skeleton-Crew-Stephen-King-Use.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this seems to be a typo in some editions or online versions. [This PDF of the book, from a Maine school district,](http://www.brunswick.k12.me.us/bhslibrary/files/2020/05/Skeleton-Crew-Stephen-King-Use.pdf) has the line:

> Five Jaunt attendants circulated, speaking in low, **cheery** voices and offering glasses of milk.

Comment: That link leads to a "we have moved" page. What is the date of this edition?

Comment: Same here, the link tells me the website has moved, the new website (Brunswick High School) there is no discernible link to the pdf. Besides how reputable is a Highschool website to claim "cherry" is a typo?

Comment: It's probably the same pdf circulating on the Internet but I don't see any of the [nine results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Five+Jaunt+attendants+circulate%22&sca_esv=566478814&sxsrf=AM9HkKlO8z-teH1VNyMevxvMBFeivY11jg%3A1695110325887&ei=tVQJZefcNZqqxc8P_uKD6AY&ved=0ahUKEwini9GGmraBAxUaVfEDHX7xAG0Q4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22Five+Jaunt+attendants+circulate%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiISJGaXZlIEphdW50IGF0dGVuZGFudHMgY2lyY3VsYXRlIkifOFDwC1jfLXABeAGQAQCYAZsBoAHBAqoBAzIuMbgBA8gBAPgBAcICChAAGEcY1gQYsAPCAgUQIRigAeIDBBgAIEGIBgGQBgg&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) that say "cheery".

Comment: @Peter Sorry, screwed up the link.

Comment: The new link shows it is a Signet edition, published by Penguin, this edition first printed 1986. "Cheery' might possibly be a correction of a misprint in OP's copy. Note though, "cherry" is used as an adjective in one other place in this book, in the last few lines of the story *Beachworld*. Neither "cheery" nor "chary" seem particularly good fits as replacements in either place.

Answer (score 0):

From context, *cherry* seems to be a typo for *chary*:

> **chary** *adj.*
> **4.a.** Careful, cautious, circumspect, wary.
> **6.** Careful not to waste or part with, frugal, sparing (of).
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/chary_adj?tab=meaning_and_use)
> (login required)</sub>

So:

> *Five Jaunt attendants circulate, speaking in low, careful voices and offering glasses of milk.*

*The Jaunt*, being first published in *The Twilight Zone Magazine* in 1981 ([Wikipedia — *The Jaunt*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jaunt)), may have been put through a magazine editor who either didn’t correct King, or over-corrected him.

You can hear the pronunciation of *chary* — which sounds just like *cherry* — at [Cambridge Dictionary — How to pronounce **chary**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/english/chary).

Comment: A typo then. Thanks!

Comment: Only two results for [a chary voice](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+chary+voice%22&sca_esv=566478814&biw=1152&bih=632&tbm=bks&sxsrf==gws-wiz-books) but better than none!

Comment: I find **chary**  unlikely in that context. There's no reason for them to be wary (or admonitory) and the meaning "frugal" is obsolescent and it doesn't apply to a voice. Unless it means something like "deliberately sparing of volume"

Comment: This word does not collocate properly with the context.

Comment: @Lambie — How do *low* and *cheery* properly collocate?

Comment: @TinfoilHat A low voice can be any number of things: light, heavy, gruff, funny, odd etc. However, cherry like the fruit is not normally a descriptive adjective except in things like Cherry Coke. :)

Comment: @TimR — Isn’t a low voice deliberately sparing of volume?

Comment: @Lambie — *cheery*

Comment: A low voice can be any number of things: light, heavy, gruff, funny, odd, cheery, depressed = whatever adjective you like. basically. cheery does not mean the volume has be be high.

Comment: @TinfoilHat  A singer might sing quietly to spare their voice, and it isn't really that there's not enough volume to go around and you have to be sparing of *it*. But I thought you might indeed have a straw to grasp at.  Maybe "cherry" reflects the old view, not uncommon in the 20th century, that a  female flight attendant played a quasi *geisha* role, soothing  the passengers with their dulcet voices.

Comment: @TimR — If this were a standardized test... **A low, _____ voice** a) *cherry* . b) *chary* . c) *cheery* ... which would you choose?

Comment: @TimR: A standardized test with a paragraph describing flight attendants from the 20th century? I'd eliminate **chary** since I've never heard that word used to describe a voice, and the choice would come down to *cheery* or *cherry*, and because of "low" and the flight attendants, I'd opt for "cherry".

Comment: If the meaning is "reticent (to disturb)" then I suppose **chary** would work. But as I said, "chary voice" is not something I've ever heard or read.

Comment: A number of Google Books hits for [**chary sounds**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22chary+sound%22&sca_esv=566478814&biw=1152&bih=632&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AM9HkKlt8R2PW11mQKQjiE2P9HcFegsOUg%3A1695148403753&ei=c-kJZc7FLbaVxc8PgIiPwA0&ved=0ahUKEwiOy8nzp7eBAxW2SvEDHQDEA9gQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22chary+sound%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIg0iY2hhcnkgc291bmQiSMA7ULQHWPk1cAB4AJABAJgBbqAB7AiqAQQxMi4xuAEDyAEA-AEBwgIEECEYCsICBRAAGIAEiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-books)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I Those examples are from one or two 18th and 19th century poetic texts. The word **chary** is not used that way in the English of the 20th century.